# CGPoint from UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to get the x and y position of a UITapGestureRecognizer, but in doing so my application crash

This is the code where I create the Recognizer

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info
{

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage * image =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 400)];

    MyImg =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

    MyImg.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(getTouchColor:)];
    [MyImg addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];    
    [recognizer release];

    [self.view addSubview:MyImg];

    [picker release];

}
```

And my event GetTouchColor

```
-(void)getTouchColor:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:MyImg];

        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

If I remove the line

```
 CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:MyImg];
```

The code works perfectly and the application does not crash.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

/ / Sorry my english from google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `recognizer` is not `nil`. Sending messages to `nil` usually returns `nil` or 0, depending on the return type, but when it’a a struct return type, the result is undefined, and may (among other things) cause a crash.

Comment: Jeff it does not return null if the line shot Gpoint it works correctly Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing, It seems, is you have missed to set the `frame` of `MyImg.MyImg`.

Comment: I changed the code creating the frame, but the application continues closing Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that MyImg variable is only declared in `imagePickerController` therefore is not reachable in `getTouchColor`, you need to include a reference to that view when calling `getTouchColor`, otherwise it won't recognize `MyImg`.